# Amazon ELB timeout on multiple instances but not on single instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an Amazon load balancer and one EC2 web instance behind it, and websites work fine, all my websites do not require long processing time, they are just some basic PHP sites, then I spun up another EC2 instance from the AMI of the first instance and attached to the load balancer, while traffic gets routed to different instances, I get some intermittent long connection timeouts, if I take out one instance and I don't get that problem. I simply don't know what's happening and why, anyone else having this particular problem?

Comment: Have you checked your logs?

Comment: Can you add more details? If you take out the first (initial) server from the ELB, does the second one work? Or is it a problem with just the second server? Are you behind a VPC, different availability zones? There are a lot of variables that could potentially causing issues.